# Mysql Daemon cannot start after upgrade from 5.1 to Mysql 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1, mysql-8.0

I preinstalled Oracle Enteprise Linux and it automatically installed Mysql Community 5.1. But I wanna update it to 8.
After update the daemon won't start and the */var/log/mysqld.log* shows that

> [ERROR] [MY-012263] [InnoDB] The Auto-extending innodb_system data file './ibdata1' is of a different size 640 pages (rounded down to MB) than specified in the .cnf file: initial 768 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!

Then I change the */etc/my.cnf* file and add

> innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend

I tried to start it again and the log file said

> [ERROR] [InnoDB] Unsupported redo log format (0). The redo log was created before MySQL 5.7.9

because if that, I moved the /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile* to backup directory and try to start mysqld again.
BUT it still won't start because the log file said

> [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
>   [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
>   [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
>   [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
>   [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the solution, I reinstall it completely with

```
yum remove -y mysql mysql-server
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/ #to make sure it completely deleted
yum install mysql mysql-server
service mysqld start
```

It works like a charm. Not recommending this solution if the database have useful data inside.

Answer (score 1):

That is a gynormous upgrade.

Plan A:  Oracle recommends doing it in 4 steps 5.1 -> 5.5 -> 5.6 -> 5.7 -> 8.0.  And, at each step, run mysql_upgrade.

Plan B:  Alternatively, you could dump the data and hope that the reload doesn't find some syntax errors.

I fear that you may have already hosed the files too much to have a successful upgrade.

Comment: what about reinstalling the whole thing?

Comment: @ChristophorusReyhan - If you have no data to save, that would probably be best and easiest.

Answer (score -1):

1. deleet the old mysql files
2. delete the old mysql container/pod
3. deploy the new mysql v 8
4. solved the issue for me